# "location.reload();"を使わずに、リセットさせる方法

Tags: javascript, html, css

下記のソースコードは、marqueeのいくつかの機能をボタンでコントロールさせたものです。
この中で、セレクトのoptionタグ内にある"リセット"は、"function marSpeed(opt){}"の中に
"location.reload();"を使っているために、ページ全体がリセットされてしまいます。
これを、*marqueeとボタンだけをリセットさせる*には、どのように書き換えたら言いのでしょうか。
ご教示ください。

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
  [data-marquee]{ display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-100%); }
 .marquee_container { overflow-x: hidden; }

    .DIRECTION {
      color: white;
      background: black;
    }

    .BLINK {
      animation: blink 1s step-end infinite normal;
    }
    @keyframes blink {
      0% { color: red; }
      50% { color: transparent; }
    }
      </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="myMarquee" class="marquee_container">
        <span id="hello" data-marquee="left" data-marquee-sec="10">
            Hello marquee!
        </span>
    </div>
    <p>
    <button id="blinkL" class="DIRECTION BLINK" type="button" onClick="hello.dataset.marquee='left'; marquee(hello); marLeft();">
        ←
    </button>
           ☆
    <select id='marSpeed' name="speedSelector" onchange='marSpeed(this)'>
      <option  value='Faster'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Faster</option>
      <option  value='Normal Speed' selected>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(Normal)</option>
      <option  value='Slower'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Slower</option>
      <option  value='Stop'>―STOP―</option>
      <option  value='Reset'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RESET</option>
    </select>
           ☆
    <button id="blinkR" class="DIRECTION" type="button" onClick="hello.dataset.marquee='right'; marquee(hello); marRight();">
        →
    </button>
    </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

    function marLeft() {
        document.getElementById("blinkL").classList.add("BLINK");
        document.getElementById("blinkR").classList.remove("BLINK");
    }

    function marRight() {
        document.getElementById("blinkR").classList.add("BLINK");
        document.getElementById("blinkL").classList.remove("BLINK");
    }

    function marSpeed(opt){
    　　var selectedIndex = opt.selectedIndex;

    　　　　hello.dataset.marqueeSec='10';
            marquee(hello);
      　　  document.getElementById('blinkL').disabled=false;
      　　  document.getElementById('blinkR').disabled=false;
    if(selectedIndex==0){
    　　　　hello.dataset.marqueeSec='5';
            marquee(hello);
    　  　}
    else if(selectedIndex==2){
    　　　　hello.dataset.marqueeSec='20'; 
            marquee(hello);
    　　　}
    else if(selectedIndex==3){
    　　　　document.getElementById('blinkL').disabled=true;
    　　　　document.getElementById('blinkR').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('blinkL').classList.remove("BLINK");
    　　　　document.getElementById('blinkR').classList.remove("BLINK");
            hello.dataset.marquee='stop'; 
            marquee(hello);
    　　　}
    else if(selectedIndex==4){
    location.reload();
        }
    }

            function marquee(elm_or_event){
        "use strict";
        function current(){
            return getComputedStyle(elm).transform.split(",")[4] || 0;
        }
        function to(px, sec){
            elm.style.transform = "translateX(" + px + "px)";
            elm.style.transition = "transform " + sec + "s linear 0s";
        }
        function scroll(px){
            elm.addEventListener("transitionend", marquee, false);
            to(px, Math.abs((px - current())/right * elm.dataset.marqueeSec));
        }
        var elm = elm_or_event.target || elm_or_event;
        var right = elm.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var left = -elm.getBoundingClientRect().width;

        elm.removeEventListener("transitionend", marquee, false);
        to(current(), 0);

        if(elm.dataset.marquee == "stop"){
            return;

        }
        if(current()+1 >= right){
            to(left, 0);
        }
        else if(current()-1 <= left){
            to(right, 0);
        }
        scroll((elm.dataset.marquee == "left") ? left : right);
    }
    marquee(hello);

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

画面読み込み時に行っていることをfunctionにまとめるのはいかがでしょう。

```
function setDefaultSetting(){
    // 左方向に10秒かけて1週する
    hello.dataset.marquee='left';
    hello.dataset.marqueeSec='10';
    // ボタンの点灯
    marLeft();
    // (Normal) を選択した状態にする
    document.getElementById('marSpeed').options[1].selected = true;
    // 元の位置に戻す
    hello.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
    hello.style.transition = "transform 0s linear 0s";
}

function marSpeed(opt){

    /* 省略 */

    else if(selectedIndex==4){
        // location.reload();
        setDefaultSetting();
        marquee(hello);
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
ただ、いただいたコードと、    <span id="hello" data-marquee="left" data-marquee-sec="10">
        Hello marquee!
    </span>，及び『方向指示ボタン』のコードを右方向用に書き換えたら、ちゃんと左端から再スタートされますが、質問のコードは左方向用で、この場合も左端から再スタートされます。ということは、"function marquee(elm_or_event){…"以下の部分をさらに『左方向用』に書き換える必要があると思いますが、頭が混乱してしまいました。この部分は、どのように書き換えるべきなのでしょうか。

Comment: 本質問から脱線しそうなので、お手持ちの現状のコードで改めて質問を立てたほうがよろしいかと思います。右方向に動いてほしいなどは、本質問からも伺えませんでしたので、その内容も含めたほうがいいですね。

Comment: 今回答をいただいたのですが、『左方向用』はjavascriptを手直すのではなく、CSSを質問用ソースコードのようにしなければならなかったようです(＊編集し直しました)。そうすると、"function setDefaultSetting(){}"内にある"hello.style.transform = ’translateX(0px)’;"の0pxは"-100%"と書き直さなければ、正常に作動しないようです。